# split a string by space and if word characters less than 2 make it single word otherwise two words

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have one requirement when i need to split the string by space and if word character length less than two characters than make it single word otherwise make it two words.

For more clear idea, here is what i want :

```
Input  : This is car
Output : {"this is", "car"}

Input  : a abcd xyz efg
Output : {"a abcd", "xyz", "efg"}

Input  : a abcd xyz efg ha
Output : {"a abcd", "xyz", "efg ha"}
```

I have tried the following code but it is not working

```
String searchValue = "a abcd xyz efg ha"
String[] separated = searchValue.split(" ");
private List<String> getFinalSearchList(String[] separated) {
    String resultString = "";
    List<String> finalSearch = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String searchString : separated) {
        if (searchString.length() > SEARCH_CHARACTOR_LENGTH) {
            resultString = "";
            resultString = resultString + searchString;
            finalSearch.add(resultString);
        } else if (searchString.length() <= SEARCH_CHARACTOR_LENGTH) {
            finalSearch.remove(new String(resultString));
            resultString = resultString + " " + searchString;
            finalSearch.add(resultString);
        }
    }
    return finalSearch;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a cleaner code but works as per requirement.

```
private  List<String> getFinalSearchList(String[] separated) {
    List<String> finalSearch = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < separated.length; index++) {
        if (index == 0) {
            finalSearch.add(separated[index]);
            continue;
        }
        String previousString = finalSearch.get(finalSearch.size() - 1);
        String searchString = separated[index];
        if (searchString.length() <= SEARCH_CHARACTOR_LENGTH || previousString.length() <= SEARCH_CHARACTOR_LENGTH) {
            finalSearch.remove(finalSearch.size() - 1);
            finalSearch.add(String.join(" ", previousString, searchString));
        } else {
            finalSearch.add(searchString);
        }
    }
    return finalSearch;
}
```

Comment: It is returning `[a abcd, xyz, efg ha]` for me. Can you please recheck ?

Comment: Please accept the answer If you are satisfied with the solution. Thank you :)

Comment: It's someone else Q's. I've upvoted BTW for your time.

Comment: Oh yeah, got confused. Thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

In the below implementation, I've modified your code to explicitly check the first 2 strings (if any) in the array.
Here is working code for the desired results:

```java
    static int SEARCH_CHARACTER_LENGTH = 2;
    static String searchValue = "a abcd xyz efg ha";
    static String[] separated = searchValue.split(" ");
    private List<String> getFinalSearchList(String[] separated)
    {
        int i = 0;
        String searchString = "";
        String resultString = separated[0];
        List<String> finalSearch = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (separated[0].length() < SEARCH_CHARACTER_LENGTH && 1<separated.length)
        {
            resultString = separated[0]+ " " +separated[1];
            finalSearch.add(resultString); i = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            finalSearch.add(separated[0]); i = 1;
        }
        for ( ; i<separated.length; i++)
        {
            searchString = separated[i];
            if (searchString.length() > SEARCH_CHARACTER_LENGTH)
            {
                finalSearch.add(resultString = searchString);
            }
            else if (searchString.length() <= SEARCH_CHARACTER_LENGTH)
            {
                finalSearch.remove(new String(resultString));
                resultString += " " + searchString;
                finalSearch.add(resultString);
            }
        }
        searchString = separated[separated.length-1];
        return finalSearch;
    }
```

---

Input: "This is car"
Output: **[This is, car]**
Input: "a abcd xyz efg ha"
Output: **[a abcd, xyz, efg ha]**
Input: "a abcd xyz efg a xyz pp ggg ha p p y"
Output: **[a abcd, efg a, xyz, xyz pp, ggg ha p p y]**